# Hide current category in Wordpress category.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot find a solution. My `category.php` shows posts from the `"products"` category. At the bottom of the posts I would like to make a "see other" section that would link to the other categories from the parent `"products"`. My code shows posts from parent `"products"` correctly, but I want to hide the category currently displayed ...
How to do it?

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'id',
'include' => 'cat',
'orderby' => 'order',
'hide_empty'=> 0,
'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
if ( $cat->category_parent > 0 ){
echo $cat->name;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do it? And what problem did you run into?

Comment: @Arsen I tried to use "'exclude' => $ category_id" to hide the category I am currently viewing, but that doesn't work ...

Comment: You can show the code where you tried to use `exclude`, maybe there was something wrong with the way you used it. But it's the right way to go.